# Battery level LED indicator - understanding issue

Tags: power-supply, transistors, batteries

I am trying to understand/simulate this circuit. I found it in [this YouTube video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tB0kCfTHLMg)

[image]

I have re-created the circuit here: https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/7gm8wpkhb8ak/battery-green-red-led/

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwu9G6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have built it on a breadboard and it kind of seems to work.

My questions:

- If I simulate this with an input of 2 to 4V the red LED never turns on.
- Can someone explain the "logic" why the red LED should turn on when the voltage drops and how the calculations are being done?

I have a very basic know-how in electronics.

Comment: Consider that the LEDs need a certain forward voltage to make current flow so that the LED will light up. Red LEDs have a slightly **lower** forward voltage than green LEDs. i.e. a red LED can work with a smaller voltage.

Comment: I haven't tried to work out how your circuit is intended to function, but if looks to me as though either the transistor is drawn 'backwards' or it's the wrong symbol and should be a PNP not NPN.

Comment: @brhans I agree, that the schematic is wrong. The green LED, diode D6 and the BC junction are all directly across the supply in forward (assuming T1 is an NPN). When the supply voltage exceeds the sum of all forward voltages, a huge current would flow. So my guess is that T1 needs to be a PNP.

Comment: Wasn’t an question about the exact same schematic asked just a few weeks ago?

Comment: In the YouTube video, the YouTuber makes a point about using the BC547 which is an NPN. His description of how it works is poor. He doesn't mention that a high current can flow with a high battery voltage. In my opinion, this is a poor design so I would advise to stay away from it. If you want a proper battery voltage indicator, use a circuit based on the TL431 shunt regulator.

Comment: Thank you for you answers. If one can point me to a good and simple low Battery Led design I would be grateful.